# Javascript not reflected on Django Project

Tags: javascript, html, css, django

I am trying to show a carousel box/ banner in my page but I am having an issue with the JavaScript it is not appearing. I have borrowed the HTML/ CSS and JS from https://codepen.io/StephenScaff/pen/egOedp/ and I am trying to apply the same concept to my Django Project.

I have added the HTML in a file called `projects.html` and in the base file I have linked a new CSS file `simple.css` with css format which in my Django project project working but my issue is when I tried to implement to JS file here is what happened in my trials.

Also the next and previous buttons are not showing

**Trial 1**
I have added under the HTML file  `projects.html` but the js code appeared under the banner image like normal text

```
{% block script %}
Added the JS code...
{% endblock script %}
```

**Trial 2**
in my base.html file I created a new file called simple.js and added in the static folder and linked it but still it didn't reflect on the server.

```
    <script src="{% static 'simple.js' %}"></script>
```

***My question***
What am I doing wrong causing this confusion and how to implement the JS code for this simple banner to my project.

Comment: It would be good if you show your base.html file and content of the simple.js file. Also as I can see it requires jquery library to work, have you included jquery library BEFORE your simple.js?

Answer (score 1):

you have fired this command after static files replace?

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, run `python manage.py collectstatic` and make sure your static files are in the correct directory (manage.py will tell you how many files it copied or changed), second of all use shift + F5 to reload the browser without cached content (or as I like to call it, *really* reload).